# How to transfer data from one tableViewCell to another tableViewCell in swift

Tags: swift

How i can transfer data from cell of tableView to cell of another tableView. I am confused about it. I can try delegate method,closure but they doesn't work on it. I want to show data of cell to cell of another tableView by single click on button. So please help me.

I try closure and delegate method to transfer data .but it doesn't work.Actually i am confused in tableView didSelectRowat function. It deal with cell on which i tapped and next step is when i tap on button this cell data shown on another cell which has different tableView & different viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first tableviewcontroller is called "ItemsViewController"

and your second view controller is called "DetailViewController"

in your ItemsViewController add this to your didSelectRowAt delegate function:

then you can send that cells information to the next view according to it's IndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {
               vc.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
               vc.name = names[indexPath.row]
               navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        } 
    }
```